# object loaded by pickle is different than the intended

Tags: python, pickle, nevergrad

I am trying to optimize a function with nevergrad and save the resulting recommendation in a pickle. But when I assert saved_obj == loaded_obj it raises an error.

To reproduce the issue I uploaded per_recommendation.pkl :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bqxO2JjrTP2qh23HT-qdr9Mf1Kfe4mtC/view?usp=sharing

```
import pickle
import nevergrad

# load obj (in the real code this is the result of some optimization)
with open('/home/franchesoni/Downloads/per_recommendation.pkl', 'rb') as f:
  r2 = pickle.load(f)
# r2 = optimizer.minimize(fn)

# save the object
with open('/home/franchesoni/Downloads/per_recommendation2.pkl', 'wb') as f:
  pickle.dump(r2, f)

# load the object
with open('/home/franchesoni/Downloads/per_recommendation2.pkl', 'rb') as f:
  recommendation = pickle.load(f)

# they are different!
assert r2 == recommendation
```

Is this normal or expected?

*off-question: in the python docs I read pickle is unsafe, is it dangerous to open (for example) the file I uploaded? is it dangerous to reveal paths like /home/franchesoni?*

Comment: Your data probably contains an instance of a class that doesn't compare equal to a copy of itself.  Try this:  `import copy`, then `r3 = copy.deepcopy(r2)`, and see if `r2` and `r3` compare equal.  If not, then it should be obvious why (probably a class instance, as noted above).

Comment: what sort of object is this? Do you *expect* `assert r2 == recommendation`? Why?

Comment: @TomKarzes or just the type doesn't implement `__eq__` and does equality by identity as inherited by `object`

Comment: I did the test @TomKarzes proposed and indeed r2 and r3 are not equal.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I expected to restore exactly the object I saved in the first place. The object is an Instumentation object of nevergrad. I can see `__eq__` when calling dir(r)

Comment: @FrancoMarchesoni what do you mean by "exactly the object"? **Why do you expect `==`** to give you `True`? Most likely, the object doesn't implement `__eq__` and just inherits `object.__eq__` which will compare equality by identity

Comment: Just intuition. I've always assumed that the test proposed by @TomKarzes will pass an assertion, I see that is not the case. However, let me see if I understood your point. Is it that maybe `__eq__` was not reimplemented and that it will only pass the assertion if the names point to the same object?

Comment: @FrancoMarchesoni If you define a minimal class `Foo`, and have `f1 = Foo()` and `f2 = Foo()`, then `f1` and `f2` will not compare equal.  If you add an `__eq__` method that compares two different instances for equality, then you can make `==` return `True` when appropriate.